# How to find list of all views which gives error in specific database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to find list of all views or store procedures that gives error while executing in database?

sometime user made changes in views (deleting the specific field in view) without checking its dependencies. All the dependent views and store procedures using the views then gives error, XXX column is missing.
Is there any specific script to check all the list of views and store procedures that gives error while executing.

Comment: If you have nested views then I would recommend starting with that list and getting rid of them. It seems so logical to nest views but in sql server the performance will be negatively impacted very seriously with nested views.

Comment: I would suggest you investigate DDL triggers (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175941(v=sql.110).aspx).  These would allow you to track (and perhaps prevent) changes to views.

Comment: You could try pulling the database down into visual studio and then doing a build on it.  But I suspect if your users are breaking views, they are probably breaking a bunch more stuff.

Comment: Write a script that looks at meta tables to get a list of views, does a SELECT * from each view, and traps any error.

Comment: Calling the sp_refreshview stored procedure on a view not only ensures the cached metadata is in sync with any schema changes, but will print an appropriate error if there are any issues binding columns due to dependencies changing.  See script posted below as the answer:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the script I use to validate view metadata and refresh it to pick up any schema or view changes... this will probably work for you:

```
-- Refresh the metadata for all views in the 'dbo' schema
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @viewName AS VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @count int

DECLARE listOfViews CURSOR FOR
    SELECT [TABLE_NAME]
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS v
           LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.sql_dependencies d ON v.[TABLE_NAME] = OBJECT_NAME(d.object_id)
     WHERE [TABLE_SCHEMA] = 'dbo' AND
           (d.[class_desc] IS NULL OR d.[class_desc] <> 'OBJECT_OR_COLUMN_REFERENCE_SCHEMA_BOUND')
     GROUP BY [TABLE_NAME]
     ORDER BY [TABLE_NAME]

OPEN listOfViews
FETCH NEXT FROM listOfViews into @viewName

SET @count = 0
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC sp_refreshview @viewName
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF XACT_STATE() = -1 ROLLBACK
        PRINT @viewName + ' has ERRORS: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()
        SET @count = @count + 1
    END CATCH
    FETCH NEXT FROM listOfViews INTO @viewName
END

CLOSE listOfViews
DEALLOCATE listOfViews

PRINT 'Total Views with errors: ' + CAST(@count AS nvarchar(10))

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Comment: Please mark as "the answer" then, and upvote as useful.  Thanks.